# Progressively update JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to show in a JPanel how an algorythm fills a matrix, step by step.

The thing is I just learnt `Thread.Sleep(number)` actually freezes the GUI and I don't think I can use Swing Timers for this. So I ran out of ideas.

First, I've got a **JPanel1** which has a JTextField and a Button. When the button is pressed, a extra frame is created with **JPanel2** in it, which will hold the representation of the table with it's size determined by the number in the previous text field. This is all handled by my **Control** class.

```
Public class Control implements ActionListener
{
    JPanel1 panel;

    public Control(JPanel1 vista)
    {
        this.panel = vista;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
       if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Push"))
       {
           int num = panel.getNumber();

           if(((num & (num - 1)) != 0) || num == 1 || num == 0)
           {
               panel.isError();
           }
           else
           {
               panel.clean();

               JPanel2 panel2 = new JPanel2(num);

               JFrame window = new JFrame("Tournament");

                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setContentPane( (JPanel) panel2);
                window.pack();
                window.setVisible(true);

               Tournament t = new Tournament (num,panel2);
               t.init();
           }
       }
}
```

**Tournament** is the class that holds the method with the algorythm. I passed the *panel2* object as an argument to "Tournament" so that the `init()` method ,which contains the algorythm, will be the one to update the panel.

```
public void init()
    {

        for(int i=0;i < this.matrix.length;i++)
           {
               for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
               {
                   matrix[i][j] = 0;
                   panel2.setCell(matrix[i][j],i,j);
               }

           }
    }
```

The `setCell(int x, int y, int z)` method changes the value of the components on JPanel2 depending on the row and column number.

So how can I make the changes appear progressively? I mean making the program wait everytime it calls the `setCell` method.

Comment: 1) Use a Swing `Timer` to call `repaint()`   2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I will try to to the Swing Timer with repaint thing first. And I'm still pretty new to this forum so thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `SwingWorker` to contain your looping code and then inside the loop you can "publish" the value that is to be used to update the GUI. In the `process()` method of the `SwingWorker` you can use Thread.sleep(...).

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more information and working examples.

If you want to use a Swing Timer, you will need to restructure you code a little. Basically every time the Timer fires you would increment the "j" variable. When "J" is greater than the max, you reset it back to "0" and increment the "I" variable. Then you update the cell and invoke repaint().

Comment: I guess the best way is to work with SwingWorker, I'll just have to find a way to publish the numbers. Thanks!